# Multi-monitor window manager

Tags: multiple-monitors

I was attempting to move my mouse pointer between my monitors today, and the weirdest thing happened. A single screen window switching application appeared, which gave me an interface to move windows between screens, all from a single screen.

I don't know how I got here, but it is exactly what I had been looking for.

Would anyone be familiar with this application?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What was the title of the (dialogue) window? Can you make a screenshot of it and include it in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to the Workspace Switcher. Check this: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html

Comment: Oh wow, that was close enough. This shows all my workspaces, while whatever i did initially only showed the current workspace.

Thanks for the help.